# Inactive internal testing track is tagged as latest version by in-app updates. How to stop this?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

I implemented in-app updating in Android, and to do so I added an internal testing track to make sure the update process worked as intented. All worked.

I set this internal release version number to be really high to distinguish it from production. For example, production version is 1.X.X, internal testing is 104.

I no longer need this internal testing track so I made it inactive and removed the testers (i.e. me).

However, the in-app update information still shows `availableVersionCode=104`. If I accept the update in-app, nothing actually downloads whereas it did when active.

How can I either remove this version entirely from internal testing, or stop in-app updates fetching this version?

I understand a last resort is to up production version to > 104 but I really do not want that.

Edit: It seems after a few days, the app no longer pulled in this testing track (but it did not stop immediately). I would still like to know how to delete internal releases.

Answer (score 0):

After removing a testing track, the build actually disappearing from Play Store can take some time (up to 3 days in my experience). This is an undocumented behaviour and caused a lot of confusion for me the first time I encountered this issue as well. I generally follow a few self-made guidelines to lessen the confusion among the development and testing teams.

- Try to keep just one testing track for all teams. But if you still want to have multiple testing tracks open, then I would suggest to have each tester added to just one of each track.
- Release a new build on `Production Track` with an updated `version code` when you are done testing the in-app update feature.
- Use `Internal App Sharing` to test in-app updates instead of using any of the testing tracks [like described here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test).